# Is it possible to use Workflow ReceiveActivity with independently written WCF service?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Suppose I had a WCF service that I have coded up, like Clemens Vasters's [XML-RPC with WCF](http://vasters.com/clemensv/PermaLink,guid,679ca50b-c907-4831-81c4-369ef7b85839.aspx), and want to stick a workflow behind it on the server side.

Is this possible to do with Windows Workflow? If so, how?

The toolbox ReceiveActivity appears to create the WCF service for me.

I'd prefer the answer in terms of Workflow 4.0, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on the service contract as plain WCF has options not exposed by a workflow service. But other than that it should be perfectly possible to create a workflow with a Receive activity to have the same service contract. That leaves the URL but using URL rewriting in IIS should be able to redirect the original URL with its svc extension to the new URL with its XAMLX extension.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm totally new to Workflow: do you mean I could recreate the contract with ReceiveActivities, then redirect to them?

Comment: Yes that is perfectly possible in a lot of cases. Otherwise you can forward the message from your original service to the workflow service but that means having 2 separate services to maintain.

Comment: Maurice, It would be a good idea to do a blog on something like this, i.e. a wf service that effectively 'implements' a wcf contract designed elsewhere. This would be of use in many Contract First scenarios which are a bit of a challenge when you want to avoid the "2 separate services to maintain". It is one way of dealing with contract first at least until we get contract first in the tooling some time in the future.